# Apex trigger takes a lot of time to access items in list

Tags: apex, trigger, performance

I have a simple Contact trigger in a sandbox org that is exhibiting some serious performance issues. After doing some debugging it looks like the issue boils down to accessing the items inside `Trigger.new` list. I mean literally just doing `o = Trigger.new[i]` appears to be really slow.

For example, this code runs reasonably quickly (processing 1000 updates in about 30 seconds):

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, before delete) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            Integer dummy = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Results from bulk data load (coming from the [bulk job details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs_details.htm&type=5) page):

> Total Processing Time (ms): 29370
>   API Active Processing Time (ms): 27229
>   Apex Processing Time (ms): 28852

However, this code takes about six minutes to run:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, before delete) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            SObject o = Trigger.new[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Results from bulk data load:

> Total Processing Time (ms): 321264
>   API Active Processing Time (ms): 319187
>   Apex Processing Time (ms): 893650

If I record the time required to execute `SObject o = Trigger.new[i]` using `System.currentTimeMillis()` I see a lot of times around 400 milliseconds.

What's going on here? Does it really take that long to access an element in a list? Is there any way around this? I thought maybe I could convert it to an actual array but apparently `toArray()` is not a method that the Salesforce version of `List` supports.

I also find it odd the the `Apex Processing Time` value is greater than the `Total Processing Time` value but maybe that's a separate issue.

#### Update 1

This is pure speculation, but this org has a lot of customizations on the Contact record, including several formula fields. I'm wondering if, as a performance optimization, you aren't working with a "live" Contact record in the trigger until you access it from the `Trigger.new` list. Maybe it's taking a while to pull the Contact record out of Salesforce's database and compute all the formula fields on the fly. Just a theory...

#### Update 2

Somebody suggested that I try this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update, before delete) {
    if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            if (Trigger.new[i] == null) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the code is still access the `List` it's just not assigning it to anything. Doing this does address the performance issue (though it's not useful code). Not 100% sure why that is, something about the assignment to a variable is causing the issue. Maybe a copy of some sort is occurring? Anyway, it's another data point.

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - (presumably) Source of the statistics: [View Bulk Data Load Job Details](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=monitoring_async_api_jobs_details.htm&type=5)

Comment: @AdrianLarson those numbers are from the Bulk Data Load jobs results page.

Comment: Sandboxes are lot slower than prod, might be that

Comment: @PranayJaiswal we have this issue in production as well. I haven't looked at the timing in production to see if it's at the same level as the sandbox, but half a second to access an item in a list of 200 items does not seem right, even in a throttled environment.

Comment: Can you check by replacing for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            SObject o = Trigger.new[i];
        } with for(Contact c: Trigger.new ){ . }. By doing this you are not creating memory for extra variables and you are type casting list in the FOR brackets itself.

Comment: @d512 have you enabled Skinny Tables in your org? Also worth raising a case with SF

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I hadn't heard of skinny tables but I really like that idea. I will definitely look into that one, thanks.

Comment: @salesforcewithfunforce doing an implicit cast didn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my test class for 2000 records in a new playground.

```
@IsTest
private class ContactTriggerTest {
   @IsTest
   public static void triggerTest(){
        Integer totalNumber = 2000;
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<totalNumber;i++){
            contactList.add(new Contact(FirstName='Felix' + i, LastName='L'));
        }

        Insert contactList;

        for(Integer i=0;i<totalNumber;i++){
            contactList[i].FirstName='Updated '+contactList[i].FirstName;
        }

        Update contactList;

        System.assertEquals(1, 1);
   }
}
```

27 sec

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            Integer j=i;
        }
    }
```

28 sec

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
        SObject o = null;
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            o = Trigger.new[i];
        }
    }
```

29 sec

```
if (Trigger.isUpdate) {        
        for (Integer i = 0; i < Trigger.new.size(); i++) {
            SObject o = Trigger.new[i];
        }
    }
```

As you can see it not much big diffidence, must be something else.